# Share array of Semaphores between two processes | linux C

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory, semaphore

Everyone, I'm here to ask you **how can I share an array of semaphores between 2 process?**?Since I created an array with `semget(..)` but I can't use `shmat(..)` on it !

With shared memory segment I usually use `shmget()` first and then `shmat(..)` so the child process can access to it.
But How it works with an array of semaphores?

I can't find any similar method able to attach() !!!

Here I Use the `semget()` to create an array of 5 semaphores:

```
/* allocate semaphores */
    if ((semid = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,5,IPC_CREAT|0666)) == -1) {
        printf("shmget() fallita sem id\n");
        perror("semget()");
        //releaseAll(bufferid,Tid,Did,semid);
        exit(-4);
```

**Here in another process I try to attach this array before use it** (but i'm using shmat and seems not working..)

```
sem_t* addr1;

    if((addr1=(sem_t*)shmat(semid,NULL,0))==-1){
        printf("shmat() fallita sem id\n");
        perror("shmat() for content");

        exit(-1);// +1 per \0 finale
    }
```

Comment: You don't need shared memory at all. Just don't use `IPC_PRIVATE`, use a real key returned by `ftok` instead, in both processes. See e.g. [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/semget.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two kinds of semaphores available on linux: sysV and POSIX.  You are using sysV semaphores.

sysV semaphores are maintained in the kernel so you don't need to allocate space for them or put them in shared memory to share them.  But you do need a way for every process using them to *find* them.  The mechanism to do that is `key_t` type.

The function `ftok` takes a pathname and an id and returns a `key_t`.  This allows every process specifying the proper path and id to generate the same `key_t`.

`semget` takes the generated `key_t`, the number of requested semaphores, and some permissions flags and returns the semaphore identifier, that is the `semid`.  The semid is used in all subsequent calls to `semctl` and `semop`.

An alternative, when you don't need to *share* the identity of the semaphore with other processes is to call `semget` with IPC_PRIVATE instead of a generated `key_t`.  You are implicitly acknowledging by the use of IPC_PRIVATE that no unrelated processes need to know the returned `semid` and thus access the semaphore.  This is useful for single processes with multiple threads that share memory and thus the `semid`; or for related processes that create the semaphores before forking but share a copy of the semid after the fork.

So your problem seems to be that you have two unrelated processes that need to share some semaphores.  For that to work you need to use the `ftok` mechanism to generate the key so everyone involved can find them.

Comment: what happen if  I want to use IPc-Private and i try to do some operation on the array direclty using the Id ? It works or I Have to use ftok? why?

Comment: I take back my previous comment.  I don't think so.  The second process would still have to call `semget` to establish permissions so even if you could pass it the `semid` it should fail with EACCES if it tried to use `semop` or `semctl`.  And if it called `semget` itself with IPC_PRIVATE it would just get a different `semid` and not share the existing semaphore.